# How to replace ${Month} as a string?

Tags: groovy, str-replace, placeholder

I want to create 'custom' placeholder for some variables in my config file. I thought I would use this syntax `${Variable_name}`. But I cannot make it work when I want to replace the placeholder with a value. I do not need to print the final value but pass it to another variable. I use println only for debugging. The string variable tmp contains the string that was read from xml config file. So I need tmp2 to have the right string where placeholder was replaced.

```
String Month = "October"
String tmp = 'This is ${Month} - a month of Love'
String tmp2 = tmp

println tmp2

//println tmp.replaceAll(~/${Month}/,Month)
println tmp.replaceAll("${Month}",Month)   //prints This is ${Month} of Love
println tmp.replaceAll('${Month}',Month)   // throws an error "WARNING: Sanitizing stacktrace:java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 0" 
// desired result to be printed is "This is October
```

Could someone help me to make it work or understand? I guess I can some other chars to mark the variable. The config file is save as XML.

**UPDATE**

I hope this code will better explain what I want to achieve

```
String Month = "October"


// content of the file (c:/tmp/conf.txt) is --> This is ${Month} - a month of Love
// I want f2 to contain "This is October - a month of Love"
// println is not a choice as I don't use println in my code
// I need a variable to contain the final string

def f2 = new File('c:/tmp/conf.txt') //use same path
println f2.text
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just use the Java [String format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) method:

```
String month = 'October'
String tmp = 'This is %s - a month of Love'
String tmp2 = String.format(tmp, month)
```

Alternately to preserve the use of `${Month}` you can use:

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine
String month = 'October'
String tmp = 'This is ${Month} - a month of Love'
String tmp2 = new SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate(tmp).make(Month:month)
```

Comment: But the placeholder is `${Month}`, not `%s`

Answer (score 6):

If you truly want to use Groovy's `GString` syntax (shell-like `"${var}"` variable replacement) against the contents of a file, what you desire is the `GStringTemplateEngine`. Having said that, the engine itself, unlike the regular compile-time `GString` facility, does not know anything about your local variable environment, so you have to pass in a map of replacement values when you execute the engine (`make()` method). Here is what it looks like:

```
import groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine

def replacements = [Month:'October']
def file = new File('template.txt')
def engine = new GStringTemplateEngine()
def template = engine.createTemplate(file).make(replacements)
println template
```

Given the file contents:

```
This is ${Month} - a month of Love
```

The following result is printed:

```
This is October - a month of Love
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do it is probably this:

```
String Month = 'October'
String tmp = 'This is ${Month} - a month of Love'
String tmp2 = tmp.replaceAll(/\$\{Month\}/, Month)

assert tmp2 == 'This is October - a month of Love'

//alternate test
def f2 = new File('~/dump.txt') //use same path
String tmp3 = f2.text.replaceAll(/\$\{Month\}/, Month)
println tmp3 //prints This is October - a month of Love
```

The problem in your code in the first sample you provided is that Groovy is taking the line

```
println tmp.replaceAll("${Month}",Month)
```

and converting that internally to

```
println tmp.replaceAll("October",Month)
```

.  When Groovy catches the double-quoted literal with a `${}` inside it (I'd say a String, but it's actually a GString), it does a replacement of the variable named inside the `${}`.  Use of a regex avoids that, as there's no variable replacement done on a regex.

Comment: So basically, I did not escape `${Month}` correctly. I provided two version but I thought that `println tmp.replaceAll('${Month}',Month)` would work.

Comment: yeah, i was puzzled by that a bit.  what's happening there is your string is being interpreted as a regex.  only this time, it doesn't have the appropriate backslashes to escape special characters, so the regex engine is seeing `{}` as repetition quanitifiers.  so, the regex ends up saying something like "find a series of $ characters, repeated Month times in a row", which doesn't make sense.

Comment: But what about `tmp.replaceAll('${Month}',Month)` I thought that "${Month} would be taken as a string

Comment: it is.  but, check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) - the first string is interpreted as a regex.